# In iframe how to "unwrap" span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

How to unwrap span tags within Iframe.

```
<span id="trans001" class="newtext">Directional</span>
```

I tried to remove using this `$('iframe').contents().find(".newtext").unwrap();`

If `remove()` means it works but content also removed. I want to retain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) instead.

```
$('iframe').load(function () {
    var $newText = $('iframe').contents().find(".newtext");
    $newText.replaceWith( $newText.text() )
});
```

The window load event executes a bit later when the complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images.